# Change syntax of texStatement cause big change of stack of syntax items

Tags: syntax

I'm trying to add some syntax support for LaTeX3. There are huge commands containing `_`, so I change the match pattern of `texStatement` in `~/.vim/syntax/tex.vim`

```
syn match texStatement /\\[a-zA-Z@_:]\+/ contained
```

I have a piece of tex code

```tex
\begin{equation}
  a + b = c
\end{equation}
```

Before I add `tex.vim`, the syntax stack of `\end` is

```
['texDocZone', 'texMathZoneC', 'texStatement']
```

After is

```
['texDocZone', 'texStatement']
```

`texMathZone` is lost and then cause problem when I use `contex` command in `ultisnip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not straightforward to change the built-in syntax to support LaTeX3. One may attempt to change the `texStatement` match rules as suggested [here: "Vim Configuration for expl3"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44624/vim-configuration-for-expl3). However, it will not work perfectly, because syntax matching is a complex beast. In particular, the rules are applied in the reverse order of definition, which means that if you overrule the `texStatement` rules, they will suddenly match more often. This (at least in part) explains your issue.

One possibility is to use the plugin [vim-expl3](https://github.com/wtsnjp/vim-expl3), which adds its own syntax rules. However, yuu need to add rules to load it yourself (it is not automatically loaded for tex files).

Another alternative is to use Vimtex. I added support for syntax highlighting of LaTeX3 syntax to Vimtex with the [v2.0 release](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/releases/tag/v2.0). This was added as a result of [this issue](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1798).

Answer (score 0):

Redefine various `texMathZone`s after

```
syn match texStatement /\\[a-zA-Z@_:]\+/ contained
call TexNewMathZone("A","displaymath",1)
call TexNewMathZone("B","eqnarray",1)
call TexNewMathZone("C","equation",1)
call TexNewMathZone('AmsA', 'align', 1)
call TexNewMathZone('AmsB', 'alignat', 1)
call TexNewMathZone('AmsD', 'flalign', 1)
call TexNewMathZone('AmsC', 'gather', 1)
call TexNewMathZone('AmsD', 'multline', 1)
call TexNewMathZone('AmsE', 'xalignat', 1)
call TexNewMathZone('AmsF', 'xxalignat', 0)
call TexNewMathZone('AmsG', 'mathpar', 1)
```